# Rails WiceGrid with multiples attributes in the same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, attributes, wice-grid

My project has 2 columns for the table user, "first_name"" and "last_name" and I want to show them in just 1 column and with 1 field to filter it (Full Name).
I have something like that:

```
g.column name: 'First Name', attribute: 'first_name' do |user|
    user.first_name
end

g.column name: 'Last Name', attribute: 'last_name' do |user|
    user.last_name
end
```

I want to do something like that:

```
g.column name: 'Full Name', filter: proc{ |q| where("first_name LIKE :query OR last_name LIKE :query", query: "%#{q}%") } do |user|
    user.first_name + ' ' + user.first_name
end
```

Is that possible?

If yes, what should I do to be able to custom the filters like that?

Thank you.

Comment: could you create a method on your user model for `full name` which returned `first_name + ' ' + last_name`?

Comment: I tried that, but WiceGird seems to read the fields independently of ActiveRecord, so it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: You could have a full_name attribute that gets updated by a db trigger or callback.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that isn't possible yet.

The createor of WiceGrid said:

> unfortunately this is not possible, but there is a simple workaround which I implemented multiple times: I create one more column name and it gets populated in before_save

Check all comments here:

https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid/issues/225

Answer (score 0):

```
g.column name: 'links' do |product|
  buffer = link_to "Show", show_product_path
  buffer += ' '
  buffer = link_to "Edit", edit_product_path
  raw buffer
end
```

Comment: I mean about the filter `filter: proc{ |q| where("first_name LIKE :query OR last_name LIKE :query", query: "%#{q}%") }`